# Solr on a separate docker container with sunspot-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, solr, docker-compose, sunspot-rails

I am trying to move a working Rails app to docker environment.

Following the UNIX(/docker) philosophy I would like to have each service in its own container.

I managed to get redis and postgres working fine, but I am struggling to get slor and rails talking to each other.

In file `app/models/spree/sunspot/search_decorator.rb` when the line executes

```
@solr_search.execute
```

the following error appear on the console:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8983):
```

While researching for a solution I have found people just installing solr in the same container as their rails app. But I would rather have it in a separate container.

Here are my `config/sunspot.yml`

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development
```

and `docker-compose.yml` files

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    (...)

  redis:
    (...)

  solr:
    image: solr:7.0.1

    ports:
      - "8983:8983"

    volumes:
      - solr-data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores

    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - mycore

    networks:
      - backend

  app:
    build: .

    env_file: .env

    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV

    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - solr

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    tty: true

    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  solr-data:
  redis-data:
  postgres-data:

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include your yml files in the question: external links can disappear anytime

Comment: @lifeisfoo done, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your config/sunspot.yml should have the following:

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: solr # since our solr instance is linked as solr
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    solr_home: solr
    path: /solr/mycore 
    # this path comes from the last command of our entrypoint as
    # specified in the last parameter for our solr container
```

If you see

```
Solr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

URI: http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?wt=json
```

Create a new core using the admin interface at:

http://localhost:8982/solr/#/~cores

or using the following command:

```
docker-compose exec solr solr create_core -c development
```

I wrote a blog post on this: https://gaurav.koley.in/2018/searching-in-rails-with-solr-sunspot-and-docker

Hopefully that helps those who come here at later stage.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare services in a docker-compose file, containers will have their name as hostname. So your `solr` service will be available, inside the `backend` network, as `solr`.

What I'm seeing from your error is that the ruby code is trying to connect at `localhost:8983`, while it should connect to `solr:8983`.

Probably you'll need also to change your hostname inside `config/sunspot.yml`, but I don't work with solr so I'm not sure about this.

Comment: When the hostname is `solr` I get another error:
`RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found Error: Not Found URI: http://solr:8983/solr/development/select?wt=json`
I will see if I find a fix to this issue. It looks like I am heading in the right path :)

Comment: Yes, now you're reaching the host and your question error is solved. I think that if you want help for the 404 problem (a solr configuration error) you should create another question. Because this isn't a docker question anymore.